# PubNative Android show multiple ads in a ListView

Tags: android, ads

I have been trying for quite a while now, I tried to modify this demo of PubNative ads for Android

https://github.com/pubnative/pubnative-android-library

What I want to do is to get multiple ads at one time request in the callback and show them in a listview, but I cant find a way to do that there is a very little help on internet about this.

My Request is:

```
 PubnativeRequest request = new PubnativeRequest();
 request.setParameter(PubnativeRequest.Parameters.APP_TOKEN, Settings.getAppToken());
 request.start(this, PubnativeRequest.Endpoint.NATIVE, this);
```

On getting successful response I create a custom adapter but it only gets one item in response all the time.

```
 @Override
    public void onPubnativeRequestSuccess(PubnativeRequest request, List<PubnativeAdModel> ads) {

        Log.v(TAG, "onPubnativeRequestSuccess");
        if (ads != null && ads.size() > 0) {
            PubNativeAdsAdapter adsAdapter = new PubNativeAdsAdapter(NativeAdActivity.this, ads);
            lv_pubnative_ads_container.setAdapter(adsAdapter);
            lv_pubnative_ads_container.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR: no - fill", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
        mLoaderContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Could anyone guide me how to achieve what I want?

Comment: I am implementing pubnative as well and facing the same problem, somehow I can't find a way to get multiple ads in the response.

Answer (score 0):

Abdul, since the request parameters is configurable, it only returns 1 ad at a time by default.

In order to be able to request more than 1 you need to set the ad_count parameter to the number of ads that you want.

```
request.setParameter(PubnativeRequest.Parameters.AD_COUNT, <NUMBER OF ADS>);
```